# Creating a clean Knockout binding without business logic (Popover - Radio Buttons)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm looking for a clean way to implement the following. Let's assume I have 5 buttons:

(Dog) - (Cat) - (Fish) - (Bird) - (Other)

In my ViewModel these buttons are represented as being a classification. So when I click the Dog button, the observable in my ViewModel should be set to Dog (this would be done through the click binding on each button).

Also, I want to show a specific style when one of the buttons is toggled (done by the css binding on the button):

**(Dog)** - (Cat) - (Fish) - (Bird) - (Other)

So for now this looks like it should turn my buttons into a radio button group. Now besides that, when I click the "Other" button I also want to show a little popover (bootstrap) in which the user can specifiy a custom value, like "Lion". Clicking an other button would  close the popover.

Now on each button I could add a binding similar to this one:

```
{ css: { 'toggled': classficationMatches('Dog') }, 
     popover: { action: 'close', id: 'mypopover' },
     click: { click:setClassification.bind($data, 'Dog') }
```

But this feels dirty. I would prefer building a custom handler and use it like this:

```
{ toggleClassification: { type: 'Dog', popover: 'mypopover' } }
```

Now it would be up to the ViewModel to decided if the popover should be visible or not and the binding would contain all the logic of adding the css binding, the click and the popover bindings to the buttons.

I started trying some things with custom bindings but this code looks even worse:

```
ko.bindingHandlers["toggleClassification"] = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var classification = $(element).attr('data-type');
        var selector = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        var pickerViewModel = new SimpleFilterSpecializationPickerViewModel(element, selector);

        // Whenever we click the button, show the popover.
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "click", function () {
            // Hide the popup if it was visible.
            if (pickerViewModel.isVisible()) {
                pickerViewModel.hide();
            }
            else {
                var requireInit = !pickerViewModel.loaded();

                // Show the popover.
                pickerViewModel.show();

                // The first time we need to bind the popover to the view model.
                if (requireInit) {
                    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, pickerViewModel.getPopoverElement());

                    // If the classification changes, we might not want to show the popover.
                    viewModel.isClassification(classification).subscribe(function () {
                        if (!viewModel.isClassification(classification)()) {
                            pickerViewModel.hide();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            $('button[data-popoverclose]').click(function () {
                $(element).popover('hide');
            });
        });
    }
};



ko.bindingHandlers["toggleClassification"] = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        // Store the current value on click.
        $(element).click(function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            viewModel.setClassification(observable);
        }); 

        // Update the css of the button.
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { css: { 'active': viewModel.isClassification(valueAccessor()) } }, viewModel);
    }
};
```

Anyone have some tips on how I could clean up my bindings so most of the 'logic' can be done in the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this "dirty" binding programmatically with
`ko.applyBindingsToNode(Element element, Object bindings, Object viewModel)`
e.g.
**HTML**

```
data-bind="toggleClassification: { type: 'Dog', popover: 'mypopover' }"
```

**JS**

```
ko.bindingHandlers["toggleClassification"] = 
{
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) 
    {
        var type = valueAccessor().type;       // 'Dog'
        var popover = valueAccessor().popover; // 'mypopover'
        var binding = { 
                         css: { 'toggled': classficationMatches(type) }, 
                         popover: { action: 'close', id: popover },
                         click: { click:setClassification.bind(bindingContext.$data, type) }
                      };
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, binding , viewModel);
    }
};
```